# Groovy remove duplicate from list using unique function

Tags: string, list, groovy, unique, soapui

I'm using soapui groovy script.
I want to remove the duplicate from a list, using the next code:

```
def  myStr = "aaaa ; bbbb ; ccccc"

def myList = myStr.split(";")

myList = myList.unique()
```

but when i tun the code i get exception:

> No signature of method: [Ljava.lang.String;.unique() is applicable for
>   argument types: () values: [] Possible solutions:
>   minus(java.lang.Object), minus(java.lang.Iterable),
>   minus([Ljava.lang.Object;), size(), use([Ljava.lang.Object;),
>   use(java.lang.Class, groovy.lang.Closure)

Answer (score 5):

Use `tokenize()` instead of `split()` which returns an ArrayList as compared to split which return a String Array.

```
def  myStr = "aaaa ; bbbb ; ccccc;"
def myList = myStr.tokenize(";")*.trim()
myList = myList.unique()
```

or use `toList()` if you are using `split()` or cast the String array to a `Set`.

However, based on the question you want to remove the duplicate items from list but I do not see any duplicate item. If you mean to remove duplicate strings from the list items then use:

```
myList = myList.unique().collect { it.toSet().join() }
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple, .split() returns an array, you just need to convert it to a (Groovy) List. Any of the following will make the unique() method work.

```
def myList = myStr.split(";").collect()
```

or

```
def myList = (List)myStr.split(";")
```

or

```
def myList = myStr.split(";").toList()
```

If you cast it to a java.util.Set, it'll only keep unique values!

```
def myList = (Set)myStr.split(";")
```

**Gotcha:** Be careful though, the strings still contain the spaces!